# Why isn't my code working? Discord.js index.js client.on

Tags: discord.js

It's not sending a message, there are no errors I tried modifying the code nothing is working the bot welcome message still works I think that it's not updating with replit.

I tried modifying the code switching some stuff around basically doing stuff if I see any flaws I made.

```
client.on('message', message => {

  // We'll want to check if the message is a command, and if it is, we'll want to handle it

  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  // Split the message into an array of arguments, with the command being the first element

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);

  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  // Check if the command is "privatevc"

  if (command === 'Privatevc') {

    // Check if the member is in a voice channel

    if (!message.member.voice.channel) {

      // If the member is not in a voice channel, send a message letting them know they need to be in one to use the command

      return message.channel.send('You need to be in a voice channel to use this command.');

    }

    // If the member is in a voice channel, create a private voice channel for them

    message.member.voice.createChannel({type: 'Voice'}).then(channel => {

      // Send a message to the member letting them know the private voice channel has been created

      message.channel.send(`Private voice channel created for you: ${channel}`);

    }).catch(console.error); // If there was an error creating the private voice channel, log it to the console

  }

});
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement. To start with, use the editor to format your code properly, and revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score -1):

This code is for Discord.js v12. If using the newest (v14) you need to use the [messageCreate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate) event instead of `message`. So the code would be:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
```

You might also enable the [MessageContent](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/GatewayIntentBits#MessageContent) and [GuildMessages](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/GatewayIntentBits#GuildMessages) intents.

```js
IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent
```

To make it all work you need to enable at least the **third** option, as you might see in the screenshot.
[image: intents]